# linux printing via lp, how I can print more than one copy?

Tags: php, linux, printing

I need to print a (custom) number of copies on a DYMO-450 labelprinter, using a apache based local linux server, running php, wkhtmltopdf, xvfb and stuff...

If have trouble with giving a number of copies to the print job. Normally it shout be done with

```
lp -d PRINTER DOCUMENT -n2 // or possibly -n 2
```

for 2 copies.

But the DYMO doesn't.

Currently I am am using this workaround, which does the job, but I am waiting up to 3 seconds between each printed label:

```
$printcmd = '';
for ( $p=0; $p < $_REQ['copies'] ; $p++ ) {
    if ($p>0) $printcmd .= '&& ';
    $printcmd .= 'lp -d ' . $cfg['labelprinter'] . ' ' . $pdf_file . ' > print.log 2>&1';
}
system($printcmd . ' &');
```

But this doesn't suck at all.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The (late) answer is, adding `-o Collate=True`

```
lp -n num-copies -o Collate=True filename
```

thanks to http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html